# Drupal redirect not working in root folder - Rewrite Rules working ok?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-7

[None of my redirects are working](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2995563) and show as **never accessed**, wondering if my **rewrite rules** are preventing it.

Can somebody help me please and confirm if the below sample result rewrite look good?

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/
rewrite '/test/' -> '/index.php?q=/test/'
local path result: /index.php
prefixed with document_root to /var/www/html/drupal/index.php
go-ahead with /var/www/html/drupal/index.php [OK]
```

**UPDATE:**

Just discovered that if I disable the root script check, then the rewrites are working.

```
if (!preg_match('/index\.php$/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {
      // Do not redirect if the root script is not /index.php.
//      $can_redirect = FALSE; //disabled
    $can_redirect = TRUE; // without the check it works
    }
```

Not sure why the check is not working since my rewrite goes to /index.php, any clues or how I can check this further?

Comment: Pay attention to security failure if you modify core

Comment: good point, hence I'm concerned to hack it this way. I'd rather want to understand why the redirect module doesn't get triggered. 

Does `!preg_match('/index\.php$/'` mean that if it doesn't come from index.php it will disable redirects?

**I expected that since my rewrite directs to index.php this IF block shouldn't get triggered to disable redirects with the FALSE flag (which is in the original code).**

Answer (score 0):

If Drupal redirects are not working on root folder eg: /var/www/html and working on some folder under root eg: /var/www/html/**test**

you should modify the .htaccess and find for these lines

```
# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /
```

and uncomment the  **RewriteBase /** line as

```
# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /
```